# How to query a number value from a drop-down menu in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

My HTML

```
  <form id="form">
        <div id="tshirtOrder">
            <button id="tshirt">T-Shirt</button>
            <label>Quantity:</label>
            <select name="tshirtQuantity" required>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>    
            </select>
        </div>
```

My JS

```
const getForm = () => {
    const formEl = document.getElementById('form')
    let tshirtQuantity = formEl.elements.tshirtQuantity.value    
}
```

I am trying to sell t-shirt item with the quantity option (number value) as a drop-down list. My question is how can write a syntax to return the quantity given in number of the value 1, 2, 3? The JavaScript I wrote always return the first option value (1) inside of `<select name="tShirtQuantity">`. I want to query the correct number value that the user selected from the drop-down menu. Thanks!

Comment: *"The JavaScript I wrote always return the first option value (1)"* - can't reproduce this behavior. If you change the selected option in the `select`, the value does change.

Answer (score 0):

The following method is old school solution.

Replace:

```
let tshirtQuantity = formEl.elements.tshirtQuantity.value
```

with:

```
let tshirtQuantity = formEl.elements.tshirtQuantity.options[formEl.elements.tshirtQuantity.selectedIndex]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.

First, the HTML. You are closing the label in the wrong place, and the HTML element you should listen to is not the `form`, but the `select`.

```
<form id="form">
   <div id="tshirtOrder">
      <label>Quantity:
         <select class="tshirt" name="tshirtQuantity" required>
             <option value="1">1</option>
             <option value="2">2</option>
             <option value="3">3</option>    
         </select>
      </label>
    </div> 
</form>
```

Then, to get the change on the element, you should add an event listener that reacts to the change.

```
const selectElement = document.querySelector('.tshirt');

selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
});
```

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll`, `spread operator` and `map` function as

```
let selectElement = document.querySelectorAll('[name=tshirtQuantity]');
let optionValues = [...selectElement[0].options].map(o => parseInt(o.value))
```

If you only want to get selected value

```
console.log(selectElement[0].options[selectElement[0].selectedIndex].value)
```

```js
const getForm = () => {
    let selectElement = document.querySelectorAll('[name=tshirtQuantity]');
    let optionValues = [...selectElement[0].options].map(o => parseInt(o.value));
    console.log(optionValues);
    
    console.log(selectElement[0].options[selectElement[0].selectedIndex].value)
}

getForm();
```

```html
<form id="form">
        <div id="tshirtOrder">
            <button id="tshirt">T-Shirt</button>
            <label>Quantity:</label>
            <select name="tshirtQuantity" required>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>    
            </select>
        </div>
 </form>
```